# Update existing Wordpress post content and custom fields with a csv file

Tags: mysql, wordpress, csv, phpmyadmin, relational-database

I have exported a CSV file using phpmyadmin that contains a sub set of data from both the wp_posts table and the wp_postmeta table using Join syntax. This data includes the post name,post content and post id from the wp_posts table and a series of custom fields from the wp_postmeta table. (eg. Artist,Producer etc). I would like to update this CSV file with a spreadsheet editor and update the currently published posts with the updated CSV file.

How do I map the columns of the updated CSV file to specific tables and also to multiple tables using the post id as the key.

Would creating two csv files from the data help? Even so, I would still need to instruct PhpMyAdmin to import to the proper table using post id as the key. Also considering that Join syntax was used to produce the query for the initial export.

The data I have exported as a CSV was a result of this query in PhpMyAdmin on my main database(Wordpress) table:

```
 SELECT p.post_name,
    p.post_content,
    p.ID,
    art.meta_value as artist,
    prd.meta_value as producer
 FROM wp_posts p
  JOIN wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta art on p.ID = art.post_id and art.meta_key = 'Artist' 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta prd on p.ID = prd.post_id and prd.meta_key = 'Producer' 
 WHERE pm.meta_key = "MediaLink"
```

Comment: I still have not been able to find a solution for this issue. It has been days, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I considered finding  help elsewhere, but PhpMyAdmin's official website uses Stackoverflow as its official support solution. Please someone help